# How can I save output of every layer of convolution neural network as an image in keras?

Tags: keras

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(1,3,3, input_shape=img.shape))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
```

How can I save output from convolution2D as an image?

Comment: See https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer

Answer (score 3):

**Getting the output of a model**

Use the `predict` method with input data to get the outputs:

```
predictions = model.predict(inputData)
```

The input data must be a numpy array with shape `(any, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2])`.

**Creating a submodel to get intermediate outputs**

Get the model you already created and find the layer you want in `model.layers[i]` or in `model.get_layer('someName')`. You could have for instance declared the layer with a name: `model.add(Convolution2D(1,3, input_shape=img.shape, name='target_conv'))`

```
from keras.models import Model

subModel = Model(model.input, model.get_layer('target_conv').output)

predictions = subModel.predict(inputData)
```

**Saving images**

This only makes sense if the convolution has 3 or less channels. Since yours has 1, it's ok, a grayscale image.

Use some library like PIL:

```
from PIL import Image

for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
    Image.fromarray(predictions[i]).save('filename'+str(i),'.bmp')
```

**Saving individual channels**

If your conv layers have more than 3 channels, the resulting image is not really meaningful to our brains... So we should save each channel independently.

```
for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
    im = predictions[i]

    for channel in range(im.shape[-1]):
        Image.fromarray(im[:,:,channel]).save('img_'+str(i)+'_ch_' + str(channel),'.bmp')
```